# I am sending the html file to browser using express but my javascript file linked to html is not working

Tags: javascript, html, express

This is my code in server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views')); 
// app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

app.get('/' , (request, response) => {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('sever is running on 3000 port.!');
});
```

In this code, I am sending the index.html file to the browser but the javascript file which is included in the index.html is not working

Comment: Did you check the JS-console in the browser for any errors?

Comment: include your index.html in code, and check browser console if there is any error